# IE11: <select> up/down button size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to make the scrollbar up/down buttons smaller (shorter) when using IE11 ?

The reason this is a problem is that we're displaying `<select>` controls, each containing 5 lines, and sometimes in IE11, the up and down buttons are *so* tall, they fill the entire space  (so there's no scroll bar inbetween).

[image]

So, basically, I would like them to have the same height as in Chrome.

Is there some CSS to change this button height ?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally bad practice to apply styles for native for elements (sometimes it's impossible to apply styles, like in your example). Better simulate this dropdown with list and than apply CSS for that (consider using plugins like [select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').select2({
    width: '150px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
  <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The reason I'm using <select> controls is that I want to let the user select more than one option per control  (i.e. they can hold down CTRL and select multiple options) and the user wants to be able to see the options they've selected...  so I do want this to be a scrollable <select>.